# moving files from tmp folder to permanent folder

Tags: php, upload

im having troubles with moving an uploaded file from temp directory to a permanent filed... please review my code. am i possibly missing something because the code just does not seem to work. it jumps straight to the else part of the if statement

```
<?php
$submit =$_POST['submit'];
if (isset($submit)) 
{   
    $tittle =$_POST['songTitle'];
    $song = $_FILES['song']['name'];//song name
    $target= 'audios/uploads'.$song;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['song']['tmp_name'], $target);// gets file from temp directory and moves it to permanent folder  

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['song']['tmp_name'], $target))
    {       
        echo "succcessful";
    }   else{

        echo 'failed';
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: is the folder you want  to upload you file in to permission 777 !?

Comment: You might not be pointing at a directory that exists. What does `is_dir('audios/uploads')` output?

Comment: no i have not added the permissions. is there anywhere i can get directions to adding the permissions for the folder? once i move everything to my hosting site, will this give me any issues 

audios/uploads/ is where my mp3s will be stored

Answer (score 1):

your target directory should be you need to add "/" at the end of your target directory and you should give folder permission to uploads directory

```
 $target= 'audios/uploads/'.$song;
```

and once your write move_uploaded_file it moves your file from tmp directory to your target directory.

You did that but you checked it again in if condition.
If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.

So your condition always printed false you just need to write it once.

your final code would look like this

```
<?php
$submit =$_POST['submit'];
if (isset($submit)) 
{   
    $tittle =$_POST['songTitle'];
    $song = $_FILES['song']['name'];//song name
    $target= 'audios/uploads/'.$song;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['song']['tmp_name'], $target))
    {       
        echo "succcessful";
    }   else{
        echo 'failed';
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can i  add the permission to my folders

Comment: windows 10 operating system, i am working on my personal laptop. ii will soon be moving the site to a free hosting service  to test the grounds. if it does well i will buy a domain.... the service is www.000webhost.com

Comment: right click on your folder and go to properties check for security tab you will find how to set permission for different user types hope this helps

Comment: all folders seem to have read and write permissions... one thing that does not seem to be ticked is the special permission

Comment: just finished giving permission to the upload directed.... i am gonna go ahead and copy the code as is and try again... please allow me a few minutes to do so

Comment: no luck... it is steal echoing the "failed" part of the if statement

Comment: i tested out your code here is working demo https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2J7FcMmVjBBNE5CTlJCeTFFaE0

Comment: maybe the problem is with my machine

Comment: i have exactly the same codes you used but only difference is, your form is in upload.php but mine is uploadfiles.php

Comment: what is the size of  file you are trying to upload ?